# Posting a message on FB that a user has installed an application (like FB app)

Tags: android, facebook

Is there a way to post if a user of my application has installed the app? Just like when Facebook for Android posts "USER installed the Facebook for Android application on his phone."
What type of message is this? I can't find it in the documentation of Graph API or maybe i just missed something. Anybody with some experience in this?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i've got the answer on FB dev forums. It's called *discovery (feed) story* and it's handled by FB only. So it cannot be controlled by the app/developer. So it's kind of automatic for our apps in a FB way if this message appears or not.

Answer (score 0):

To do something similar, you would need to prompt the user to login and prompt them for the publish_stream extended permission. You could then post on their wall that they are using your application.  But there is not a built in method to format it like the native clients can.

Comment: Well, my app has all of them and it can post to users walls already. I really meant the way i asked. Not a simple status/feed/wall post. There are different methods for posting different things like notes, links, likes, albums, ect. you can also format it like the native clients. So, how can i post the install status of the app, like the facebook app "USER installed the Facebook for Android application on his phone.". does. Its an "activity message" or what and there are no methods for them in graph api as i see. This type of msg is for app install statuses only. Dunno if you know what i mean.

Comment: Its definitely not available from the graph api.  Sorry.  And only the native Facebook for iPhone/Android apps have access to do that - not any third party facebook clients.

Comment: thank you! it seems it depends on FB's behavior if the message appears or not that somebody has installed your app and it's called "discovery story".

Answer (score 0):

You would have to [create your own Facebook Application](https://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php) and post to wall/feed via the FB app.

Comment: It only makes the origin of the message to be my app.